# laravel controller problems wih if-statement

Tags: laravel, if-statement, controller

in controller

```
  if ($userLike) {
     $comment->likeIt();
     return response()->json(['status' => 'success','message'=>'liked']);
  } else {
     $comment->unlikeIt($$userLike->id);
     return response()->json(['status' => 'success','message'=>'unliked']);
 }
```

i want to have if(!$userLike)  but i have one error in console `POST http://learn.com/comment/like 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you posted data using javascript (ajax or jquery), you should post data with CSRF-TOKEN. This link will help you : https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

You should add this line,

> 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')